# How to unbind an external event when a controller/$scope is destroyed?

Tags: events, controller, angularjs

Supposed I have a controller for a page that is being rendered into an `ng-view`.

This controller binds to some events of an external source (such as an application-wide message bus) to update its model. This basically works very easy:

```
function MyController ($scope) {
  $scope.bar = '…';

  externalSource.on('foo', function (data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.bar = data.bar;
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is: How do I unbind the controller from the external source once the view it it is associated with is not longer shown?

Is there something such as a `dispose` event or something similar?

Or is my approach completely wrong, and I should deal with something like that somehow else? If so, how?

Comment: In case you use jQuerys **on('event', ...)** method you could just simply call **off('event')** to remove the event. Or did I got you wrong?

Comment: This not an angularjs question in particular. It depends on the external event resource you are using.

Comment: Yes it is. I know how to unbind, but I do not know when / where to do it. This depends on the lifecycle of a controller, and this for sure is related to AngularJS.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To execute event unbind when controller's scope is got destroyed use:

`$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { /* Unbind code here */ });`

See [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) docs for more info

Comment: I think you meant `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { ... })`

Answer (score 3):

Use $routeChangeStart or $routeChangeSuccess events:

```
function MyController ($scope) {
  $scope.bar = '…';

  externalSource.on('foo', function (data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.bar = data.bar;
    });
  });

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current){
    // unregister listener
    // externalSource.off ....
  });
}
```

... or `$destroy` event:

```
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    // unregister listener
    // externalSource.off ....
  });
```